# pfgplots y axis exponential progression

Tags: pgfplots, grids

TLDR: how to create a grid in pgfplots with Y axis progressing as n^0.286 instead of ymode=log.

I have to build a diagram with this grid:

[image]

X axis is temperature in Celsius, and Y axis is pressure in hPa. But the thing is that Y axis it not in log mode and inverted: it actually progress as an exponent which is n^0.286.

For example, if I try to create this grid with y axis in log mode with:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ymode=log,
      log ticks with fixed point,
      ymin=95,
      ymax=1020,
      ytick={100,200,...,1000},
      y dir=reverse,
      xmin=-95,
      xmax=45,
      ylabel=p (hPa),
      xlabel=T,
      grid=both,
      width=15cm,
      decoration={name=none},
    ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I obtain a grid that does not superpose to the intended one:

[image]

The intended grid has y axis not in log mode; should progress exponentially in the form n^0.286.
Is this possible to achieve with pgfplots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-95, xmax=45,
ymin=95, ymax=1020, y dir=reverse,
ytick={100,200,...,1000},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, precision=0, relative*=2},
xlabel=T, ylabel=p (hPa),
grid=both,
width=15cm,
y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^0.286}},
y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^(1/0.286)}},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}\end{document}
```

[image: A graph with a special scaled y-axis]